# Not able to working with popup webpages using casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am new to casper js. I am not able to click a button on an overlay page. Can you tell me how to work with overlay page using casper js?

Comment: Please can you add a bit more, what type of overlay are you using? What have you tried etc. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Well, these events should help you :

```
casper.on('popup.created', function() {
    this.echo("url popup created : " + this.getCurrentUrl(),"INFO");
});

casper.on('popup.loaded', function() {
    this.echo("url popup loaded : " + this.getCurrentUrl(),"INFO");
});
```

And here an exemple :

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.clickLabel("Activate your account");
            // */mail/* = RegExp for the url
    this.waitForPopup(/mail/, function(){
        this.test.pass("popup opened");
    });
    this.withPopup(/mail/, function(){
        this.viewport(1400,800);
        this.test.pass("With Popup");
        //following, a 'wait instruction' because I have a redirection in my popup
        this.waitForSelector(".boxValid", function(){
            this.test.assertSelectorHasText(".boxValid", "Inscription confirmed");
        });
    });
});
```

To know how it works, look at the doc.